# How to use logback for several web apps on Tomcat7?

Tags: tomcat7, logback

I can successfully configure logback for a single web app and deploy it to Tomcat7 with the dependent jars in WEB-INF/lib.  Then, when I move my dependent jars to the lib folder in CATALINA_HOME, it seems that the logback.xml config file is not found.  I have a separate logback.xml file for each web app, sitting in the classes folder of each deployed war file.  I have separate logback config files for each web app because I want each web app logging to a different rolling file appender, if possible.  With some quick google searches, I failed to find documentation for this style of setup.  Can anyone point me to a helpful resource, or just some good advice?

Comment: why? is it about saving memory? how much of a gain is it?

Comment: Why move the dependent jars to the lib folder in catalina_home?  Yes, it was done to save memory.  Most of the web apps have common dependencies.  Also, I was running out of PermGen space after several start and stops of the web apps.  I've also increased the MaxPermSize to deal with that.  I do not know the specific reduction in memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

My boss, Venu, solved this problem yesterday by following a hunch.  I suggested that he try to force tomcat to use logback for all of its logging, and then we may be able to control our logging in each of the web apps.  When he tried that, it worked great.  We then decided we did not need to log to different files for each web app because we can grep by the logger name, as our logging pattern includes it.  A google search finds plenty of blog posts on how to force tomcat7 to use logback.